# WebApi idle time unauthorized exception

Tags: asp.net-web-api, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, idle-timer

I am using the asp.net webapi. in the webapi i am using the identity authentication. after sometime the webapi throws an unauthorized access exception.approximately this happens after idle time about the 10minutes.

Comment: What's "identity authentication" for you? Please, so your auth configuration

Comment: Asp.Net 4.5.1 we have identity authentication options. so using code first and using the microsoft inbuild classes we can generate the register classes and login.